# Error generating docx with opentbs : the textbox tag disappear

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm trying to use OpenTBS on my project to generate automatically a Resume using a word template (.docx)

the template contains multiple images for the frame of the template.

when I try to generate the file with my data, i noticed with the debug option that the opening tags  disappear when I use block=tbs:row inside.

here is my php code :

```
$domains=array(
        array('id1'=>"xxx",'id2'=>"xxx"),
        array('id1'=>"yyyy",'id2'=>"yyyy"),
        //...
);
$tbs->LoadTemplate('mytemplate.docx', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
$tbs->MergeBlock('domain', $domains);
```

on my docx side :

```
[domain.id1;block=tbs:row] :
[domain.id2]
```

these tags are inside a table which is inside a textbox.

after 2 days debugging I realized that some opening textbox tags disappear on generation causing an xml parsing error opening the document

edit : After some other tests, it's when I use the block tag inside a textbox that the bug appears.

thanks for your help.

Matt.

Comment: Finally, after several tries, I succeeded to update the template removing the textboxes.

Comment: Is this command fixing the problem if you call it just before the block merge ? `$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_ELEMENTS, array('mc:Fallback'));`

Comment: Yes it works with it Thank you !